# Making getElementsByTagname to return as an array on <body> tags

Tags: php, dom

Hi anyone can figure this out as im trying to get all the text within all the body of html, but the returns are already combine string of all the text instead of array, but if i specify  it returns an array but with  its not working. As i need them to be in array for data maniputaion thanks

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$content = $dom->getElementsByTagname('body');
/*** the array to return ***/
$out = array();
foreach ($content as $item)
{
    $out[] = $item->nodeValue;
}
return $out;

<html>
    <title> Food Wars</title>
    <body>
        <p>paragraph definition</p>
        <span> Super Wars </span>
        <b> This is a text </b>
        <div> Testing automatics </div>
       <h4>Toys</h4>
       <h4>Problem</h4>
       <h4>Solution</h4>
       <h4>Discussion</h4>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a minimal code example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: work with $content object  - https://eval.in/888687

Answer (score 0):

use `strip_tags()` functions as `$out[] = strip_tags($item->nodeValue);` to remove `html` tags from a string